# Amazon Lex - Barge In

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I have a Lex bot that is called from Amazon Connect. I have figured out how to allow barge-in from the Connect Get Customer Input. However, that's where it ends. When my Lexbot prompts for my slots, it isn't allowing the caller to barge-in. I figured that the session attribute set in Connect would carry the barge-in to the slots, but it doesn't. Is there a way to allow our callers to barge-in with the slot prompts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to barge-in either using DTMF or voice. No configuration is required for DTMF and it should interrupt the prompt.

For voice barge-in, you need to set the session attributes in the `Get Customer Input` block as defined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/get-customer-input.html#get-customer-input-bargein). That is, the following attribute needs to be specified:

```
Key: x-amz-lex:barge-in-enabled:[intentName]:[slotToElicit]
Value: true
```

Specify the `intentName` and `slotToElicit` in the above key for which this functionality should be enabled. Note, wildcards (`*`) can be used here to enable this for multiple slots/intents.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do have the barge-in working on the initial intent. However, when it prompts for the slot values, Lex isn't allowing barge-in. I used the same method that you have mentioned there. I suppose it is possible that barge-in is such a new feature that it isn't implemented for Slots yet?

Comment: As per the docs, it should be implemented for slots as well. What are the session attributes that you have set on the Connect Get Customer Input block? Also mention the intent name and slots defined for the Lex bot.

Comment: I just found why I was having this happen. The code that I was using actually had a step in it to clear all sessionAttributes. This included the Barge-In attribute. Instead of clearing all sessionAttributes, I modified the code to only reset the values that are necessary. The prior developer on this was a bit heavy handed with clearing things out. However, in his defense, we weren't setting attributes like Barge-in when he was working on it.